# Error When Retrieving Multiple Collections in Mongo/Express/Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building a page which needs to retrieve and list data from several different Mongodb collections. I've been doing separate queries in the Express router function then bunging the results into an array which is passed to the page where the relevant data for each section are accessed. This has worked ok so far with up to three queries, but, if I add a fourth query I get an error.

The router function looks like this:

```
router.get('/thetest',function(req,res){
    var finalResult = {};
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
        if(err){
            console.log("Connection Error",err);
        }else{
            var collection = db.collection('cats');
            collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error retrieving cats");
                }else if (result.length){
                    finalResult.ctlist = result;
                    console.log("cats OK");
                }
            });
            var collection = db.collection('mice');
            collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error retrieving mice");
                }else if (result.length){
                    finalResult.mclist = result;
                    console.log("mices OK");
                }
            });

            var collection = db.collection('cheese');
            collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error retrieving cheese");
                }else if (result.length){
                    finalResult.chlist = result;
                    console.log("Cheese OK");
                }else{
                    console.log('No Documents');
                }

            });
            var collection = db.collection('mice');
            collection.find({}).sort({tailLength:1}).limit(3).toArray(function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error retrieving  alert bookings");
                }else if (result.length){
                    finalResult.mtlist = result;
                    console.log("Mouse tail length ok");
                    res.render('thetest',{
                        "thelist":finalResult
                    });
                }
                db.close();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

(using dummy collection names)

So, there are four queries made to three different collections. The results are listed in a Jade template using an each loop.

If I comment out any one of the four queries and just run the other three it works fine: the results are listed on the page. If I uncomment and run all four queries then Node will choke and, obviously, nothing is listed on the page. None of the collections are above about half a dozen documents in size with a handful of fields in each.

I'm pretty new to all this and I understand that this may not be the best way to do what I am attempting.

Can anybody a) explain where I'm going wrong and/or b) suggest a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is due to your code.

Node.js is an asynchronous programming language, so all the operations works parallely.

In your code 'db.close();' close the database connection. For eg. if all the db operation works parallely and the 4th one (in your code) execute firstly then it close the database connection. So it is not a good programming style.

So you can use 'async' library for solving this. 
https://github.com/caolan/async

Sample code :

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback){
    dbOperation1(query, callback);
  },
  function(callback){
    dbOperation2(query2, callback);
  },
  function(callback){
    dbOperation3(query3, callback);
  },
  function(callback){
    dbOperation4(query4, callback);
  }
],
function(err, results){
  if (err) {
     renderError(err);
  } else {
     renderHTML(results[0], results[1], results[2], results[4]);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you're right about it being my code. I've only recently started trying to learn node.js with mongodb and I'm still doing a lot of trial and error. If you were doing this where would you put the render function and the db.close function? Or would you even do it like this? Sorry for being such a newb.

Comment: Put the render function after all the operation ie., it is acutally a callback function. You just go through the 'async 'library.

Comment: I still don't fully understand this aspect yet, but you have put me on the right track, so I'll dive back in and try and learn it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment all four condition then I am pretty sure that you are commenting `res.render('thetest',{
                        "thelist":finalResult
                    });`

Hence code is chocked. Because express API always wait for response and if you not provide response sentence, then for some time is going to wait and then crash out.

Solution : You must write your response statement out of condition.

Comment: It's not that as I've been moving the res.render() function out of any commented code blocks and, as I say, with 3 of the4 queries intact it works ok. Adding a 4th causes it all to fall over.

Comment: Sorry But I am not getting your problem. You mean to say, when you add fourth collection it will crash. Can you tell me which one you comment when it work fine.

Comment: Yes, exactly that! I've been staring at it all morning wondering what is going on. ANY three of the queries and it's fine, so it can't be a syntax error, but I can't seem to add a 4th.

Is this even the best way to go about getting data from multiple collections to use on a page? How else can it be done?

Comment: Do you try to remove limit from last collection?